# Is it possible that a primary key is autoincrement with alphabet ? like A ,B ,C ,D

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I want to know about primary key ,when we need autoincrement values like 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 .......n in mysql table , so we can do  bellow code

```
  CREATE TABLE `categories` (
      `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `category_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );
```

but when we need autoincrement values like A ,B ,C ,D ,E ........ in mysql table SO is it possible ?

```
  CREATE TABLE `categories` (
          ??????????
          `category_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        );
```

Comment: *"Is it possible that a primary key is autoincrement with alphabet ? like A ,B ,C"* Short answer: No    long answer: Yes/Maybe but you would have to write custom code yourself which is most likely prone to race condications and it will cause hard to debug bugs in the future.. **So i advice to drop this idea**

Comment: No..It doesn't make sense of  `AUTO_INCREMENT `, It's only applicable on `INT()`

Comment: *"No..It doesn't make sense of AUTO_INCREMENT "* Well @NeelRathod `A` -> `B`  is also a "incrementation" ascii decimal wise ?

Comment: You could write a UDF which would map an integer to a sequence of letters.

Comment: @RaymondNijland If you consider `A` -> `B` will be incremented, Then how long you increment it? up to `Z` only?

Comment: to much trouble.. @TimBiegeleisen if range `A` -> `Z` then you have a new range? `AA` -> `AZ` end so on?

Comment: *"Then how long you increment it? up to Z only? "* @NeelRathod see above comment.. Annyhow this incremention/conversion is to "hard" to

Comment: @RaymondNijland I agree with you to drop it.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have seen a MySQL question on this site which does this.

Comment: *"I have seen a MySQL question on this site which does this."* i didn't say it's impossible .. @TimBiegeleisen by all means share the link.. i wonder how they did it assuming they also solved possible race condications..